# Trouble Importing Image React

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a React.JS tutorial and I'm having problems displaying an image. I don't get any errors but the image is not displaying. Below is the component and import code. Thank you.

------- Data.js-->

```
export const homeObjOne = {
  id: "about",
 ...
  imgStart: false,
  img: require("../../../images/svg-1.svg"),
  alt: "Car",
 ...
};
```

------- Index.js-->

```
import {
  .....
  Img,
} from "./InfoElements";

const InfoSection = ({
  ...
  img,
  ImgWrap
 ...
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      ...
              <ImgWrap>
                <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
              </ImgWrap>
      ...
    </>
  );
};

export default InfoSection;
```

Answer (score 1):

Need add .default after require("**").
like require("**").default

```
export const homeObjOne = {
    id: "about",
    ...
    imgStart: false,
    img: require("../../../images/svg-1.svg").default,
    alt: "Car",
    ...
};
```

Comment: Awsome it worked! Thank you.